# Change appearance of UINavigationBar from solid to transparent

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to achieve the exact same effect as the Photos app on the iPad: solid black navigation bar during the gallery controller, then transparent when viewing a photo.

After I initialize my navigation controller in the AppDelegate I can change the style using the below code, but not outside the AppDelegate. However once the navigation controller is on screen and set once, navigationBar becomes a read-only property.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can share how this is done. Thanks.

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Comment: that is not transparent, its actually hiding the navigation bar..

Comment: Yes it hides it initially. But tapping reveals a transparent navigationBar with the photo behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINavigationBar in `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent` `barStyle` doesn't fix it's place as it normally does in other styles. In `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent` style it just overlaps on your view and contents of views are translated up and `view` height is also increased.

if you're showing photos then first hide your navigationBar :

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Now set your navBar's style to `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Then show your imageview (or scrollview with picture- depends on your logic). Then on tapping on your imageview you can show and hide bar)

```
 // Show/Hide bar
 // Let say you've a bool 'shown' for current status of navbar's visibility.
if (!shown) {
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}else{
     [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
shown = !shown;
```

Hope this'll do it. ANd never forget to rechnage barStyle to UIBarStyleBlackOpaque once you exit gallery.

Comment: Thanks, you're a legend. I must say that is a bizarre way of getting it working.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to display navigationBar at the Gallery so there no need to change anything but after selecting a photo, keep the NavigationBar hidden in the PhotoViewController.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
 {
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
 }
```

and in ViewWillAppear

```
-(void) viewWillAppear 
 {
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
 }
```

And then create a custom method implementing UITapGestureRecognizer where on a single tap display the navigationBar by setting hidden property to YES.